# how to copy files to different path with Powershell?

Tags: powershell, filepath, file-move

I am trying to copy files with powershell.

```
$datestamp = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd")
    Copy-Item -Path \\User\LS\ADMIN\HW\DATA\Payroll\$datestamp\*.txt -Destination C:\Users\User1\Desktop\New folder
```

The files that I am trying to copy are txt type and path for this and files are located two folders down from $datestamp. I've tried with this code and its not copying the files to path that I wanted. Is there any ways to fix this code to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are after is a loop. This will cycle through all `*.txt` files in the location and copy them as requested.

```
$datestamp = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd")
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path "\\User\LS\ADMIN\HW\DATA\Payroll\$datestamp\" -Filter "*.txt"
Foreach($File in $Files) {
    Copy-Item -Path $File.FullName -Destination "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\New folder\"
}
```

A one liner (piped) version would look like this:

```
Get-ChildItem 
    -Path "\\User\LS\ADMIN\HW\DATA\Payroll\$((Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd"))\" 
    -Filter "*.txt" `
    | % {
        Copy-Item 
            -Path $_.FullName 
            -Destination "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\New folder\"
    }
```

All new lines can be removed from the sample, did it this way for formatting otherwise it appears like this.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "\\User\LS\ADMIN\HW\DATA\Payroll\$((Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd"))\" -Filter "*.txt" | % {Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\New folder\"}
```